# Flutter, PaintingStyle.fill not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class PaintHalfHexagon extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.34);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.26,
        size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.28);
    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.34);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.26,
        size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.28);
    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.34);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.34);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // return oldDelegate._lineOnefraction != _lineOnefraction;
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

When I stroked it, the shape came out perfectly, and when I filled it to fill the color, it came out in a very strange shape.

```
PaintingStyle.fill
PaintingStyle.stroke
```

What`s the problem and how to solve this?

Comment: Out of the two, which shape do you want?

Comment: I think he want second one filled.

Comment: @JigarPatel I want to fill it but it came out in a very strange shape like first picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to draw an object with the shape of the 'stroke' version, but filled like the 'fill' version. The problem is that calling `moveTo` breaks your current path and starts a new one at the coordinates you specify. Even if you draw your separate paths back together so that they *look* like they touch, as far as the engine is concerned they are not contiguous. Therefore, when you use `PaintingStyle.fill` it has no idea that it should fill that space in. The result in your example is that it closed the path of each bezier separately, and filled each bezier separately.

You can refactor to remove the `moveTo` calls, e.g.:

```
path.moveTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.34);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.26,
    size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.28);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.26,
    size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.34);
path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.34);
```